# Why am I getting different results after reading a file, depending on how the Spark context was created?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to get started with doing k-means clustering in Spark, based on [this example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/KMeansExample.scala).  The example code says:

```
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KMeansExample")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    // $example on$
    // Load and parse the data
    val data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/kmeans_data.txt")
    val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
```

But when I run this on my cluster, it just prints

```
20/04/22 17:46:12 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

over and over.  Most answers on the interwebs say this means I'm asking for too much resources, but this is a trivial program (clustering six datapoints), so I thought maybe I'm just not setting it up correctly.  I compared to an earlier Spark program that ran successfully on my setup, and it created the context differently, using a session builder.  So I changed the code to:

```
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("kmeans").getOrCreate()

    // Load and parse the data
    val data = spark.read.textFile("/project/sample_data.txt")
    val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
```

But now I'm getting a compile-time error:

```
[error] /s/chopin/a/grad/jstrout/project/goes-clustering-study/kmeans-complete/src/main/scala/kmeans.scala:18: Unable to find encoder for type org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector. An implicit Encoder[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] is needed to store org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
[error]     val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
[error]                              ^
```

I don't understand why it compiled before before, but does not in this version.

Any clues?

Comment: Do you realize that `data` is an RDD in your first snippet and a Dataset in the second one?

Comment: No, I didn't realize that.